# Finding a cut-off value in a graph

Tags: calculus, statistics

I am trying to find an analytical solution to this problem: I have some observations in the following graph (in the link) and I need to predict the red cut off. I actually don't know the function of the line and I have not tried to fit it to a known model because depending on the observations, the function might change. How can I find the red cut off (or at least predict something similar)? 
My impression is that the values start increasing and even though there are fluctuations, the minimal values are considerably higher after the red line compared to before the red line. How can I find this solution mathematically? I supposed I have to define an epsilon I tolerate. Do you have another idea how to predict the red cut off?
I acknowledge that my problem is a bit vague but any suggestion might help! Thanks!

[graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UAFd.png)

Comment: You have not given a criterion for the red cut off that I can see. Can you say "The red cut off occurs when..."?

Comment: The red cut off is actually the point with the highest F-measure. But I need to predict it from this graph, without knowing the labels. The red cut off happens at 273 levels. So if I predict a similar value of levels, it is still ok.

Comment: Still absolutely no idea why you have a vertical line where you have it, and you do not seem to be able to articulate why it is there and not somewhere else. All I see is a graph - what makes it "the point with the highest F-measure"? What does that mean?

Comment: I know that is the best point for my problem because I know the labels of the data. That is the point where I get the highest precision and recall combined. If I did not know the labels, is it possible to find this point or a interval just by the shape of the graph?

Comment: I have seen some methods that find an elbow in the curve, but it is not exactly the case here.

Comment: You are still not providing the slightest clue why this point is special. Maybe you need to go to someone who knows the details of your topic and the meaning of labels and F-measure?

Comment: Yes, maybe. Thanks anyway!